# GCM duplicated messages

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I have an app based on Google Cloud Messaging and it was working well. Now (today) all of a sudden it started having a problem we've never seen before. For each message sent between devices, the receiving device will get it twice. The first will arrive almost instantly (within less than 3 seconds of sending). The second arrives a few minutes later. There are two devices in the test, the problem is the same whichever one is the sender/receiver. So if a device sends a few message to the other, the other will get them pretty much instantly--but then at a later time, it will receive a barrage of messages which are the second copies of the messages it has received.

I have put in breakpoints to make sure that the sending device wasn't the culprit: the message was sent exactly once (i.e. the web service for sending was called exactly once--and the code for the backend, which runs on Google App Engine, hasn't changed for ages.) However, the message somehow gets delivered to the receiving device twice. By using breakpoints I also made sure our own code on receiving side isn't responsible: it is verified that `GCMIntentService::onMessage()` indeed gets invoked twice for each sent message.

We also made sure the registration id in our database is the latest. At this point I'm stumped and need ideas to make any further progress. So any ideas?

Comment: I cant confirm this as a user. Since about 7 hours I receive every message twice. From Facebook, Gmail and so on. Very frustrating... I suspect a problem with gcm

Comment: Aeno: thanks for the confirmation. Would you please edit your post to say "can confirm" instead of "cant"--that's what you meant. Anybody from Google Android team watching this space? Is there any official word on this?

Comment: Same here. Our still-in-development app receives duplicate messages since yesterday.

Comment: @user2113392: yes, I did mean 'can' but editing period is over... ;)
seems as the issue is fixed by google

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/EHZUTEJMeyw

Check the official GCM thread above. Everyone is experiencing this issue. Google's fault!

Comment: Thanks John. And it seems fixed today.

Answer (score 0):

We also have the same problem, and we are sure we don't send the message twice.
It could be an issue related to what's explained here about "Canonical IDs": http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html

> [...] However, if a bug in the application triggers multiple registrations for the same device, it can be hard to reconcile state and you might end up with **duplicate messages**.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. We have many apps integraded with MyMalcom and Urban Airship and all of them are getting pushes twice since Monday. We have checked also the canonicalId changes as suggested by Ferran, but the delivered to GCM messages are ok (no cannonical Id changes).