# Double gcm notifications

Tags: android

I'm testing how to use gcm today. It works ok but I get double notifications.

What I mean about double notifications is few minutes after the notification came, there's second notification with exact same content as the first.

I'm testing the notification using [GCM with PHP (Google Cloud Messaging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging)

I don't know where I'm going wrong.. I'm testing using emulator and a real device
This is the logcat debug

```
02-27 16:05:36.192: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(513): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
02-27 16:05:36.192: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(513): GCM IntentService class: mypackage.GCMIntentService
02-27 16:05:36.201: V/GCMBaseIntentService(513): Acquiring wakelock
02-27 16:05:36.221: V/GCMBaseIntentService(513): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-DynamicSenderIds-2
02-27 16:05:36.312: V/GCMBaseIntentService(513): Releasing wakelock

.
.
.

02-27 16:11:14.282: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(513): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
02-27 16:11:14.282: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(513): GCM IntentService class: mypackage.GCMIntentService
02-27 16:11:14.291: V/GCMBaseIntentService(513): Acquiring wakelock
02-27 16:11:14.302: V/GCMBaseIntentService(513): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-DynamicSenderIds-3
02-27 16:11:14.402: V/GCMBaseIntentService(513): Releasing wakelock
```

Comment: even facebooks push has the same problem for a few days ;) i am experiancing it same notif 2wise so should be a problem with the server -- not cause f ur implimentation dont worry

Comment: So the error is at the google? It's not on my code? I'm implementing it as exactly as the http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html said

Comment: i hope so .. beliving on the senario that facebokks app also gets 2 notif for same msg :)

Comment: We too. We are experiencing the same problem in all our apps since Monday.

Comment: By the way, as I said, we are in all our customer apps integrated in our platform (MyMalcom) are suffering this duplicates, but we are wondering why software like Whatsapp doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Another related post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102055/gcm-duplicated-messages/15110473#15110473

Comment: Thanks for the comments and link to the related post(it didn't appear when I google search and making this post). It appears that I'm testing the gcm at the bad moment lol.

Link to the google group about the problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/EHZUTEJMeyw

Comment: are you sure you have not spooked up your app at the configuration end? May be you have registered duplicate apps there?

Comment: No, I implemented the gcm test app directly from the google official site. See the comments above as why this happens. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you register your BroadcastReceiver once and only once, because it fires for every time that you register your BroadcastReceiver. You will get problems if, for example, you register it in your `onResume` method of your `Activity` but you do not unregister it in your `onPause` method.

Comment: Yes I only have one receiver. Apparently it's google fault, please see the comments posted above. Thanks :)