# GCM Pushing The Same Message Multiple Times (PushSharp)

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, google-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

## Problem:

I'm developing an android app with Xamarin that uses [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp).  I am using GCM to send messages to the clients so I can update certain things if the app is open.  GCM seems to be sending the same message to the same device multiple times.

---

## Logcat:

```
Thread started:  #12
09-17 08:40:34.307 I/PushSharp-GCM(20855): GCM Message Received!
09-17 08:40:34.317 V/GCMBaseIntentService(20855): Releasing Wakelock
09-17 08:40:34.327 V/UpdateSignalReceiver(20855): Message Receieved: *****
Thread finished:  #12
The thread 'Unknown' (0xc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
09-17 08:40:34.787 V/PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver(20855): OnReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
09-17 08:40:34.787 V/PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver(20855): GCM IntentService Class: rAMP_TabletV1.x5.GCMIntentService
09-17 08:40:34.787 V/GCMBaseIntentService(20855): Acquiring wakelock
Thread started:  #13
09-17 08:40:34.807 I/PushSharp-GCM(20855): GCM Message Received!
09-17 08:40:34.817 V/GCMBaseIntentService(20855): Releasing Wakelock
09-17 08:40:34.817 V/UpdateSignalReceiver(20855): Message Receieved: *****
Thread finished:  #13
The thread 'Unknown' (0xd) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
09-17 08:40:35.817 V/PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver(20855): OnReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
09-17 08:40:35.817 V/PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver(20855): GCM IntentService Class: rAMP_TabletV1.x5.GCMIntentService
09-17 08:40:35.817 V/GCMBaseIntentService(20855): Acquiring wakelock
Thread started:  #14
09-17 08:40:35.857 I/PushSharp-GCM(20855): GCM Message Received!
09-17 08:40:35.857 V/GCMBaseIntentService(20855): Releasing Wakelock
09-17 08:40:35.867 V/UpdateSignalReceiver(20855): Message Receieved: *****
Thread finished:  #14
The thread 'Unknown' (0xe) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
09-17 08:40:36.277 V/PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver(20855): OnReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
09-17 08:40:36.277 V/PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver(20855): GCM IntentService Class: rAMP_TabletV1.x5.GCMIntentService
09-17 08:40:36.277 V/GCMBaseIntentService(20855): Acquiring wakelock
Thread started:  #15
09-17 08:40:36.327 I/PushSharp-GCM(20855): GCM Message Received!
09-17 08:40:36.327 V/GCMBaseIntentService(20855): Releasing Wakelock
09-17 08:40:36.337 V/UpdateSignalReceiver(20855): Message Receieved: *****
Thread finished:  #15
The thread 'Unknown' (0xf) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
09-17 08:40:36.717 V/PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver(20855): OnReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
09-17 08:40:36.717 V/PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver(20855): GCM IntentService Class: rAMP_TabletV1.x5.GCMIntentService
09-17 08:40:36.717 V/GCMBaseIntentService(20855): Acquiring wakelock
Thread started:  #16
09-17 08:40:36.747 I/PushSharp-GCM(20855): GCM Message Received!
09-17 08:40:36.757 V/GCMBaseIntentService(20855): Releasing Wakelock
09-17 08:40:36.757 V/UpdateSignalReceiver(20855): Message Receieved: *****
```

---

## Sending the Message:

Each device is registered and the registration id is stored in a database.  I check the version number and the previous registration id to make sure that there are no duplicates, and also make sure I have the correct registration id. (I have double checked to make sure that there are no duplicates in my database)

The update is called from a WCF service, and it will send the messages to all the registered devices. The method is only called once, and `AllRegisteredDevices` is a distinct list of device ids to send the message to.

```
foreach (var deviceId in AllRegisteredDevices)
{
    var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
    webRequest.Method = "post";
    webRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
    webRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));
    webRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));
    var postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message="
        + value + "&registration_id=" + deviceId + "";
    Byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    var dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
    dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    var responseFromServer = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    streamReader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    webResponse.Close();
} // end loop
```

---

## Receiving The Message:

I have a custom Broadcast Receiver to handle the message, depending on what the value of "message" is. The PushService passes it along to the receiver.

### Push Service

```
protected override void OnMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
{
     Log.Info(PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver.TAG, "GCM Message Received!");

     string message = intent.Extras.GetString("message");
     var theIntent = new Intent(UpdateAction);
     theIntent.PutExtra("message", message);
     SendOrderedBroadcast(theIntent, null);
} // end OnMessage
```

### UpdateSignalReceiver

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new string[]{PushHandlerService.UpdateAction}, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
public class UpdateSignalReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {       
        MyActivity TheActivity = ((MyActivity )context);
        string message = intent.Extras.GetString("message") ?? "";
        Log.Verbose("UpdateSignalReceiver", "Message Receieved: " + message);
        if (message == "foo")
        {
            TheActivity.DoSomething();
        } // end if
        else if (message == "bar")
        {
            TheActivity.SomethingElse();
        } // end else if
        else
        {
            TheActivity.CatchAllMethod();
        } // end else
        InvokeAbortBroadcast();
    } // end on receieve
} // end UpdateSignalReceiver
```

---

## Environment

- Samsung Galaxy Tab 3
- Only factory installed apps (no other apps using the same GCM)

---

## Research:

- [GCM Multiple Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102055/gcm-duplicated-messages) - 
  *had to do with maintenance of the registered devices, which in my case they are all unique, no duplicates, and just to be sure, when populating my `AllRegisteredDevices` in the GCM call, I select distinct.*
- [GCM Duplicated Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102055/gcm-duplicated-messages) - *[GCM bug dating back to Feb, 2013](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/EHZUTEJMeyw).  I doubt the bug is still in place, though it is possible.*

---

## Question:

**Why am I receiving the same message repeatedly, when I'm only sending it once?**

Comment: So it ends up in the OnMessage 1+ times? If not, do you have another installed app using the same GCM?

Comment: That is correct, the `onmessage` fires multiple times, typically 3 times separated by milliseconds. I'm using Samsung tab 3's exclusively, and this is the only app that's not factory installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to go with a throttling approach.  While this is not perfect in its implementation, the general idea is as follows:

- All Messages are given a Unique ID (Guid)
- The Broadcast Receiver has a static list of Guids containing the last 20 Message Ids we received and handled
- Only do work on messages that have an id not contained in our list, so we know it's a new message to this device.
- Limit the List to 20 IDs so it doesn't grow out of control. (20 seems to be more than enough, as repeat messages typically come in 3, sometimes 5 iterations)

---

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new string[]{PushHandlerService.UpdateAction}, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
public class UpdateSignalReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static List<Guid> _Last20MessageIds;

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {       
        Guid MessageId;
        // Pull the MessageId from the intent
        String MessageIdString = intent.Extras.GetString("message_id" ?? Guid.Empty.ToString());
        Guid.TryParse(MessageIdString, out MessageId);


        if (_Last20MessageIds == null)
        {
            _Last20MessageIds = new List<Guid>();
        }

        // Make sure we didn't already receive this Message, then do work
        if (MessageId != null && MessageId != Guid.Empty && ! _Last20MessageIds.Contains(MessageId))
        {
            DoSomeWorkWithIntent(intent);


            // Add the guid to the message id list
            _Last20MessageIds.Insert(0, MessageId);

            // Trim the list to the most recent 20
            _Last20MessageIds= _Last20MessageIds.Take(20).ToList();
        }
        InvokeAbortBroadcast();
    } // end on receive
} // end UpdateSignalReceiver
```