# android: Check if GcmListenerService has bees started

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, listener

I have a question about GcmListenerService.

I have a service which receives GCM messages:

```
public class MyGcmListener extends GcmListenerService {  

    @Override
    public  void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    Log.i("mytag", "message received");
    ....
    }
}
```

Usually the main activity of my app startes it:

```
 context.startService(new Intent(context, MyGcmListener.class));
```

But it seems that sometimes two service objects are created and a receiceive doubled log messages:

```
01-07 17:15:02.090    3655-3668/package: message received
01-07 17:15:02.090    3655-3668/package: message received
```

So I want to try if the service is already active when I start it from main activity:

```
if (!MyGcmService.isActive())
   context.startService(new Intent(context, MyGcmListener.class));
```

One of the solutions could be to make a variable `boolean active` which could be set `true` in `onStartCommand()` method and `false` - in `onDestroy()` (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600207/how-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-on-android)). But GcmListenerService does not have `onStartCommand()` method.

So how can I implement it? Have already seen such a problem?

Comment: When you use `startService`, in case service already exists it is not created twice, so you don't need to check whether it exists before starting it. As reported in `startService` spec: "If this service is not already running, it will be instantiated and started (creating a process for it if needed); if it is running then it remains running."

Comment: Why don't you use a broadcast receiver and intent service so you don't have to start the service?

Comment: @thetonrifles, yes it should be so, i also have read the specification. But in fact it receives messages twice as you can see

Comment: @Keith, I use the service that Google has recently recommended

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137660/android-gcm-duplicate-push-after-notification-dismiss) could help.

Comment: I know that it could help, but without it I have the [following problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627053/how-to-run-gcmlistenerservice-in-foreground) - the service does not receive anything in an hour

Comment: Solving a problem the wrong way - creating another problem, that's not the way to go.