# GCM upstream messages are triggered twice

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, duplicates

I use gcm for instant messaging.
I have the problem that upstream messages coming from anyone's device are sent twice with a delay.
That means the first message is sent immediately and the second same one is sent some minutes or hours later.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: This question seems similar to this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102055/gcm-duplicated-messages).

Comment: Could it be an issue with the ACK that you are returning to CCS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. I just catch all duplicates according to my business logic.